# Specify command line for application while creating service using SRVANY.EXE

Tags: windows, service, vb6, srvany

I am creating service in VB6 application using SRVANY.EXE as show [in this link](http://www.vbrad.com/article.aspx?id=92) . But my application requires a command line to work.So if i want to pass command line to my application then what to do? The command line is fixed and not change. So how it can be given while creating service?

Comment: Have you just tried putting the parameters on the end of the application path, exactly as you would from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

I use these *exact* steps at work to create a service for my VB6 apps.  However I have the path in step 15 to be a batch file (.bat file) that they runs the VB6 app with the required arguments.